# Unable to import 'decouple' - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

i already did `pip install python-decouple` on my terminal, but vscode keep saying that is unable to import.

Comment: perhaps VSCode is using a different python interpreter than your terminal... did you configure the interpreter in vscode as well? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Check your python interpreter in both VScode and terminal. Are they same or different?

Comment: If it's flagging the word `from` as an error, that suggests the previous line has an error such as a missing right-parentheses.

Comment: just configure the interpreter in vscode to python 3.8.1 64-bit, but the error is still there

Comment: the word "from" is flagging because it says that is unable to import 'decouple'

Comment: forget, it was it, i change the interpreter in vsc and i forgot to do "pip install python-decouple" again, now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check which environment your vscode is using

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

If you did `pip install python-decouple` in a virtualenv, then you need to point the vscode python interpreter to that environment.

To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Comment: yes, you are right, i did it but i forgot to install it again after change the interpreter. Thanks